# Selenium locator for span loaded with AJAX

Tags: css-selectors, selenium-ide

I'm new to Selenium IDE and can't find exact answer to my question elsewhere.
I have Login form that loads error message in span tag using AJAX.

Code looks like this:

```
<dd class="field-error-template atk-form-error">
<i class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"></i>
<span class="field-error-text">Incorrect login information</span>
</dd>
```

I used following Selenium code to verify that this span appeared on screen:

```
waitForElementPresent css=dd.field-error-text span
```

However it returns false so any other ideas? I don't want to put delay as I don't think it is good practice.

Thanks,

Gita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got your classes mixed up; the selector should either be this

```
dd.field-error-template span
```

Or this

```
dd span.field-error-text
```

(or use both classes)